# Quasi-distribution for the composite (fermions + bosons) system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, bosons, quasiprobability-distributions

Let us have a system which consists of $N$ electrons with the spin (i. e. fermionic subspace has a dimension of $4^N$) and $K$ bosonic modes (let us consider $K=1$ for simplicity). Let us say, we obtained (numerically) the density matrix of the system. One can easily obtain the [Wigner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution) (or [Husimi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husimi_Q_representation)) quasi-distributions for the bosonic subpart (at least in the case of $K=1$) by calculating the partial trace over fermions. For example by [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705020) formula
$$
W(\alpha, \alpha^*) = \frac{2}{\pi} \text{Tr}\left[\rho_\text{f} D(2\alpha) \exp\left(i \pi a^\dagger a\right)\right],
$$
where $D()$ is a bosonic [displacement operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_operator), $a$ - bosonic [annihilation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators#:%7E:text=The%20mathematics%20for%20the%20creation,while%20all%20other%20commutators%20vanish.), and $\rho_\text{f}$ is a reduced density matrix (after [tracing out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace) the fermionic degrees of freedom).

I would like to know if there are any convenient ways to calculate any quasi-distribution for the fermionic part of the system (perhaps, after tracing out the bosonic degrees of freedom)? I am looking for closed formula to be able to do it numerically.
It is easy to do in case of spinless fermions (one can easily define the coherent spin state and corresponding Husimi quasi-distribution) but i do not understand what to do in this case.